# Encrypt numeric data while preserving inequalities among ciphertexts

Tags: encoding, cryptography, encryption

How to encrypt numeric data such that the cipher text produced by the encryption function is numeric, also `Enc[m1] < Enc[m2]  where m1 < m2.`

I have gone through number of references all pointing to [Format Preserving Encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption). However, no open source code implementation is available for it.

Is there a way (Encryption or Encoding) which can conceal the data with the aforementioned properties by using Java or C# ?

I want to encrypt numeric data within the range of [1 – 50] to cipher text within the range of [1000 - 5000]. I am trying to implement Secure Inverted Index mentioned in [Enabling Search over Encrypted Multimedia Databases](http://www.ece.umd.edu/~minwu/public_paper/Conf09/0901secureMMsearch_spie09.pdf).

Comment: More specifically, what you are looking for is [homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption).

Comment: @GregS - Homomorphic Encryption is used to perform arithmetic operations on the ciphertexts, can you please elaborate that how it be used to ensure Enc[m1] < Enc[m2] where m1 < m2.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've got a basic contradiction here.  If you encrypt a number of values and somehow maintain the sort order among them, then someone, knowing that "abc" encrypts to 567 and "abe" encrypts to 569, will know that 568 => "abd".  (Not that your encryption algorithm would be that naive, but you're seriously weakening anything you do manage to devise.)

Encrypting to a number is not difficult, if you allow the number to be longer than your cleartext.  (After all, characters themselves are just numbers with special meaning.)  A simple approach is to just decode the cyphertext into octal, but other techniques will produce slightly more compact representations of decimal digits.

Comment: I am dealing with the numeric data and just want to maintain the order of the cipher text according to the plain text – not the difference among the consecutive values. If I can encrypt/encode [1,2,3] to [999,3192, 4519] it’s perfect for me. I think by ignoring the difference among the consecutive values there is no way an attacker can learn the next value in the plain text.

Comment: @Shani -- I'm sorry, but what you want to do will seriously weaken the encryption algorithm.

Comment: @Hot-Licks- Okay, is there a way to implement it even with weak security model? I want to conceal (while preserving the order) the frequencies of words in the inverted index so that the database administrator cannot learn the actual frequencies. The words in the inverted index are concealed with well-proven encryption algorithm i.e., AES, while order preserved concealed frequencies are used to sort the result of lookup queries.

Comment: @Shani -- If you read the article you referenced, they describe the "encryption" scheme they use.  It's in the paragraph starting "To perform order preserving encryption...".  That should be an adequate description to duplicate what they did (which is, at best, simply obfuscation).